# Converting Rails 6/edge app from sqlite3 to Postgresql to deploy on Heroku (failing) (have researched similar questions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails 6 (on the 'edge branch' of Rails), I tried to deploy it to heroku and got the `sqlite3` error, which comes with instructions of how to handle it:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

I created a `sqlite_to_pg` branch, and I followed these instructions:

1) Updating my Gemfile, removing `gem 'sqlite3'` and adding `gem 'pg'`

2) Running `bundle install`

3) Converting my database.yml from this:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Into this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I noticed the formatting looked different, so also tried this:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_production
```

I `git add .` and `git commit -m "..."` my changes

I then ran `git push heroku master` and got the same set of errors that I had the first time:

```
Enumerating objects: 1963, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1963/1963), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1868/1868), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1963/1963), 601.88 KiB | 5.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 1963 (delta 1255), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.0.2
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.1
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.1
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.3.0
remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.3.0
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Installing erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.2
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.2
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.3.3
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.3.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching popper_js 1.16.0
remote:        Installing popper_js 1.16.0
remote:        Fetching method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Fetching thor 1.0.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.0.1
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.12.2
remote:        Installing ffi 1.12.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Fetching mini_magick 4.10.1
remote:        Installing mini_magick 4.10.1
remote:        Fetching semantic_range 2.3.0
remote:        Installing semantic_range 2.3.0
remote:        Fetching sqlite3 1.4.2
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching will_paginate 3.1.8
remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.1.8
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.10.9
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.10.9 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Installing i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching warden 1.2.8
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.8
remote:        Fetching rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Installing rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Installing marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.7.4
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.7.4
remote:        Fetching puma 4.3.3
remote:        Installing puma 4.3.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.4.6
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.4.6 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.2.1
remote:        Installing sassc 2.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ruby-vips 2.0.17
remote:        Installing ruby-vips 2.0.17
remote:        Using activesupport 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching image_processing 1.10.3
remote:        Installing image_processing 1.10.3
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using activemodel 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Using activerecord 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using activejob 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actionview 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Installing friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Using actionpack 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actioncable 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using activestorage 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actionmailer 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using railties 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Fetching simple_form 5.0.2
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Using actionmailbox 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actiontext 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching responders 3.0.0
remote:        Installing simple_form 5.0.2
remote:        Installing responders 3.0.0
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using webpacker 4.2.2 from https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git (at master@cb4e4c8)
remote:        Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Using rails 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching devise 4.7.1
remote:        Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Installing devise 4.7.1
remote:        Fetching bootstrap 4.4.1
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap 4.4.1
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20200409-257-12wdlj9.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
remote:         --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:         --with-sqlcipher
remote:         --without-sqlcipher
remote:         --with-sqlite3-config
remote:         --without-sqlite3-config
remote:         --with-pkg-config
remote:         --without-pkg-config
remote:         --with-sqlcipher
remote:         --without-sqlcipher
remote:         --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --with-sqlite3-include
remote:         --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:         --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:         --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          sqlite3
remote:        Bundler Output: The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.1
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.1
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.14.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.3.0
remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.3.0
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Installing erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.2
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.2
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.4
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.3.3
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.3.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching popper_js 1.16.0
remote:        Installing popper_js 1.16.0
remote:        Fetching method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Fetching thor 1.0.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.0.1
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.12.2
remote:        Installing ffi 1.12.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Fetching mini_magick 4.10.1
remote:        Installing mini_magick 4.10.1
remote:        Fetching semantic_range 2.3.0
remote:        Installing semantic_range 2.3.0
remote:        Fetching sqlite3 1.4.2
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching will_paginate 3.1.8
remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.1.8
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.6
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.10.9
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.10.9 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Installing i18n 1.8.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching sprockets 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching warden 1.2.8
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.8
remote:        Fetching rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Installing rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Installing marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.7.4
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.7.4
remote:        Fetching puma 4.3.3
remote:        Installing puma 4.3.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.4.6
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.4.6 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.2.1
remote:        Installing sassc 2.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching ruby-vips 2.0.17
remote:        Installing ruby-vips 2.0.17
remote:        Using activesupport 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.4.0
remote:        Fetching image_processing 1.10.3
remote:        Installing image_processing 1.10.3
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using activemodel 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Using activerecord 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using activejob 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actionview 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Installing friendly_id 5.2.5
remote:        Using actionpack 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actioncable 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using activestorage 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actionmailer 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using railties 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Fetching simple_form 5.0.2
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 5.12.0
remote:        Using actionmailbox 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Using actiontext 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching responders 3.0.0
remote:        Installing simple_form 5.0.2
remote:        Installing responders 3.0.0
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using webpacker 4.2.2 from https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git (at master@cb4e4c8)
remote:        Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Using rails 6.0.2.1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 6-0-stable@c316787)
remote:        Fetching devise 4.7.1
remote:        Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Installing devise 4.7.1
remote:        Fetching bootstrap 4.4.1
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap 4.4.1
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20200409-257-12wdlj9.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
remote:         --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:         --with-sqlcipher
remote:         --without-sqlcipher
remote:         --with-sqlite3-config
remote:         --without-sqlite3-config
remote:         --with-pkg-config
remote:         --without-pkg-config
remote:         --with-sqlcipher
remote:         --without-sqlcipher
remote:         --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:         --with-sqlite3-include
remote:         --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:         --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:         --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_fbeb88babc2fb757c504b83e6b4f3069/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          sqlite3
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to taaalkco.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/taaalkco.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/taaalkco.git'
```

I also found this tutorial (https://dev.to/dauncy/transitioning-from-sqlite-to-postgres-in-rails-56on) and ran: `rails db:create && rails db:migrate`, but I don't think this should change things.

It did not remove any information stored on my database though, which I found odd. When I go to localhost:3000, all my previous records are still there. [Edit: I restarted the server and all my records were dropped.]

I also followed the guidance at the bottom of the Heroku help page and checked my `gemfile.lock` and there are no instances of `sqlite`.

I'm very unsure how to proceed.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get you want to push feature branch onto Heroku. Builds works only with master branch, so you want to do smth like this:

`git push heroku sqlite_to_pg:master`

Feel free to review docs [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code)

Comment: Thank you, that was it